# How to disable Backbone code to call an underscore template in non-essential pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an app that uses Backbone on the client side and Rails on the back end.

My Backbone code calls an underscore template in this manner:

```
var todo = Backbone.View.extend({
    .
    template : _.template( $('#todo_rows').html() ),
    .
}
```

However, there's only one page on the site which would need to call this template, and the Backbone js loads on every page.  That means that there will be a JS error on the other pages which don't have the "#todo_rows" underscore template defined.

One solution would be to create a blank "#todo_rows" template section for all the other pages, but this strikes me as a major hack and not the best way to deal with this problem.

What is the best way to disable the code to call a template in Backbone?  It needs to be disabled if you are not on the home page OR if you are not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore's `template` is happy with receiving an empty string as argument. As `$('#todo_rows').html()` returns `null` if the `#todo_rows` element does not exist, you can easily avoid the JS error by using the or-operator idiom:

```
template : _.template( $('#todo_rows').html() || '' ),
```

which means "use an empty string as dummy template if the real one is not available".

Another, Rails-specific workaround for this problem (and a neat approach in general) is to add the `ejs` gem to your project's Gemfile, which allows you to put each template in a separate `.jst.ejs` file in `app/assets` and have the Asset Pipleline compile it to a `JST` object that can be accessed by your view to get the template content:

**templates/todo_rows.jst.ejs**

```
<% // Your template (content of former "#todo_rows") here %>
```

**todo_rows_view.js**

```
//= require templates/todo_rows

var todo = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : _.template(JST['templates/todo_rows']),
    // ...
}
```

This avoids the roundtrip to the DOM and makes it possible to nicely organize the templates into multiple files, but has the drawback that the template string will be sent as part of the JavaScript code for every page including it.

Comment: Thank you, I've gone with your first suggestion to use the or-operator.